# Add Google search to codeigniter 4 website

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Hi i need help integrating google search engine into a website. I know how to generate the code and have done so in the past for non codeigniter projects and everything worked well.

In codeigniter, it is always returning no results on every query and am stuck on where the issue is. I was wondering if it was the way codeigniter's folder structure is arranged or the .htaccess  files codeigniter comes with?

```
<script async src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=29f801461421f4ef0"></script>
<div class="gcse-search"></div>
```

Comment: You're going to need to be a little more specific here. What code do you currently have that you've tried to integrate Google into?

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry for that, i have edited it.

Comment: Can you include more information, what are the errors thrown etc. This tells us nothing to start with.

Comment: If you can integrated successfully this search bar into other not Codeigniter based websites the you must be [learn about fundamentals of Codeigniter framework usage](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/index.html)